# Github action on scheduled time not running at all?

Tags: node.js, github-actions

Attempting to run a file on a scheduled time (increasing the schedule later) but for some reason, it is not running at all. I am not sure if I have written it correctly.

```
name: updateStandingsDB

on:
  schedule:
  - cron: '*/1 * * * *'

jobs:
  build-node:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: node:16
    steps:
      - name: git checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install
        run: npm install
      - name: Prem
        run: node update-standings/prem.js
```

Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation at GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule) you cannot set it the way you did:

> The shortest interval you can run scheduled workflows is once every 5 minutes.

So I would recommend either trying `*/5` (or even `*/10`) or simply committing with a fixed time (which is IIRC also in UTC) while you debug.

Comment: I tried that, and it still didn't get triggered. Do you know if I am setting up action correctly? I am trying to run a specific file on my repo in the 'update-standings' folder.

Comment: I would recommend the simplest possible execution action and the simplest (fixed time?) setup. You can only try with new commits so it can be finicky -- but I set a number of them by now (mostly daily or less frequent).  The rest looks fine to me from a glance.

Answer (score 0):

see [documentation at GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule)

Note: The schedule event can be delayed during periods of high loads of GitHub Actions workflow runs. High load times include the start of every hour. If the load is sufficiently high enough, some queued jobs may be dropped. To decrease the chance of delay, schedule your workflow to run at a different time of the hour.